# System.out.printf("is %d times \n", count) in Scala

Tags: scala

i want to systemout(String,int), but my string dont work cause i have %d inside it .. 
how ca i do that in Scala - Error multiple markers at this line ?

```
System.out.printf("is %d times\n", count)
```

Answer : println("is %d times\n".format(count))

or something like that :

```
System.out.printf(String.format("Muster:%%%ds\n", len), s2)
```

Answer : println("Muster:%%%ds\n".format(len).format(s2))

thanks for any idea !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
println("is %d times".format(count))
```

if you want to use `printf` you can do:

```
def systemout(str: String, i: Int) = System.out.printf(str, Array[AnyRef](new Integer(i)) :_*)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use string interpolation in Scala:

```
val count = 5
println(s"is ${count} times")
```

More information: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: Or f"is $count%d times", for something closer to the old `printf`.

Comment: In this case you can omit the brackets; `println(s"is $count times")`